# Obter uma imagem do corpo de um email, gravar na base de dados ou em memória e mostrá-la num novo Viewer

Tags: sql, email, vb.net

Estou a tentar construir um visualizador de E-mails.

Para tal, acedo ao meu servidor de IMAP e obtenho email, utilizando a DLL `ComponentSoft.Net.Mail`.

Após obter a mensagem, pretendo apresentá-lo no meu visualizador.

No entanto, estou a ter problemas com os Linked resources, isto porque não pretendo guardá-los fisicamente mas apenas guardar em `MemoryStream` ou Array de bytes na BD.

O problema está na obtenção da imagem de qualquer um destes sítios, porque pretendo voltar a colocá-la como CID no Body do email, para  que o meu visualizador a apresente. No entanto não estou a conseguir obter esse CID.

O que fazer?

Para melhor compreensão coloco o código que estou a usar:

```vb
 Dim img As Drawing.Image = Drawing.Image.FromStream(email.LinkedResources(i).GetContentStream)
 Dim converter As New Drawing.ImageConverter
 Dim byteImage As Byte() = converter.ConvertTo(img, GetType(Byte()))
 Dim base64 As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage)
 Dim LR As String = "cid:" + email.LinkedResources(i).ContentIdentifier
 If MailBody.Contains(LR) Then
     MailBody = Replace(MailBody, LR, "<img src=data:image/gif;base64," + base64)
 End If
```

Comment: Já pensou em converter a imagem pra String base64?

Comment: Por acaso estava agora a fazer um teste utilizando um Handler ashx e dei conta q m dava jeito ter a imagem em base64. Alguma dica sobre como converter a imagem para base64?

Answer (score 1):

Como eu propus nos comentários, parece ser a solução ideal converter a imagem para String base64 e depois apenas desconvertê-la. Como eu estou me baseando que você esteja usando C#, minha resposta será em C#, se não for eu corrigirei ela depois.

Meu código de exemplo foi retirado do site dessa [pergunta da SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/converting-image-to-base64).

### Convertendo para base64

```
public string ConvertImageToBase64(byte[] imageFile){
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageFile);
  Image imgContainer = ScaleImage(Image.FromStream(ms));//Salva a imagem com novas proporções, caso necessário
  ms = new MemoryStream();
  imgContainer.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); //Modificar o Png para o formato da imagem
  return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```

### Retornando de uma base64 para imagem

```
public BitmapImage Base64Image(string imgBase64){
  byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);    
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
  ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
  BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
  bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
  return bitmapImage;
}
```

Basicamente isso faz a conversão e desconversão, caso você queira usar a imagem internamente ao programa, como um `BitmapImage`.

Caso você queira criar um arquivo com a imagem, como é visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827081/c-sharp-base64-string-to-jpeg-image):

```
public void SaveImage(string imageBase64, string filePath){
  byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64.Content);
  using (var imageFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)){
    imageFile.Write(bytes ,0, bytes.Length);
    imageFile.Flush();
  }
}
```

Essa conversão também pode facilitar o armazenamento, caso necessário.

Comment: Olá @felipe.avelar. Antes de mais obrigado. Já fiz a conversão (aliás tinha conseguido testar ontem ainda antes de sair, a conversão). Por acaso estou a usar VB.Net, mas consegue-se adaptar bem o código. No entanto, tenho uma dúvida: para apresentar a imagem no meu "MailBody", devo adicionar a string Base64 como o cid? Ou criar uma tag de imagem (<img src....> ) ?

Comment: @N0C0ddE, vai depender do seu leitor de email. Caso seja um webmail ou o cliente seja compatível com o [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), é possível embutir a imagem na própria tag img da seguinte forma: <img src="data:string_base_64"/> (o que é equivalente ao CID), sendo que a maioria dos clientes de email hoje dão suporte a isso. Caso você realmente tenha o desejo de utilizar o CID é possível também, nesse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures) da SOEN você vê como aplicar as duas formas.

Comment: infelizmente já tinha tentado seguir esses passos e não está a funcionar. Eu faço o replace do cid no MailBody da seguinte forma `  Dim LR As String = "cid:" + email.LinkedResources(i).ContentIdentifier
                        If MailBody.Contains(LR) Then
                            MailBody = Replace(MailBody, LR, "<img src=data:image/gif;base64," + base64)
                        End If`

Comment: Mas você chegou a tentar utilizando o próprio cid? No link que eu te mandei tem [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9110164/1606920) que fala como utilizar o cid com base64.

Comment: Pelo que percebi dessa resposta, isso seria para embutir directamente num leitor de email. A questão é que eu estou a criar a minha própria página de visualização, em código. Não sei se isso tinha ficado bem explicito

Comment: @N0C0ddE, infelizmente eu só conheço essas duas formas de embutir uma imagem em um email. ://
Você está criando o seu próprio leitor, no caso?

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela ajuda. Sim, estou a criar um visualizador que, conforme expliquei no primeiro post, vai ao meu servidor de IMAP obter os emails e mostra-os aos utilizadores.

Comment: Outra questão que me deparei entretanto foi que, por exemplo num servidor de email normal, os Linked Resources fazem parte de um handler attachment.ashx com um id que corresponde a um owaID. Eu já utilizei esses owaIDs em situações no passado, mas apenas para mail UniqueIds. Haverá forma de converter Linked Resource Ids para OwaIds para poder utilizar no meu handler (que já criei entretanto)?

Comment: @N0C0ddE Se você tem outras dúvidas, coloque na pergunta ou se achar que não cabe na mesma pergunta abra outra pergunta que faremos o possível para ajudá-lo. Aqui é diferente de fórum. Precisamos de **perguntas** e **respostas** bem organizadas. Não queremos resolver só seu problema, queremos que esse conhecimento fique fácil para outras pessoas achar.